# how to compile android emulator just the opengl module, android-emugl

Tags: android, build, opengl-es, emulation

I was wondering, how I can compile just the module android-emugl inside the android emulator repository. I know that android use the Android.mk file to drive the build process, but I cannot see how to build just that module by itself.

Any help will be really appreciate it.

Thanks,